# Show that $A \cap (B \Delta C) = (A \cap B) \Delta (A \cap C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show that $A \cap (B \Delta C) = (A \cap B) \Delta (A \cap C)$.

Attempt : $A \cap (B \Delta C) = A \cap [(B - C) \cup (C - B)] = [A \cap (B-C)] \cup [A \cap (C - B)]$.

From here I am unsure what to do.

Comment: To be able to use A∩(B−C)=(A∩B)−(A∩C) would be nice, no? Wait... is this true after all? :-)

Answer (score 1):

The direct approach to showing identities (namely showing two inclusions) would go something like:

Suppose $x \in A \cap (B \Delta C)$. This means that $x \in A$ and $x \in B \Delta C$, so case 1: $x \in B, x \notin C$. Then $x \in A \cap B$, and $x \notin A \cap C$, so $x \in (A \cap B) \Delta (A \cap C)$. The other case, $x \in C, x \notin B$ is symmetrical. This shows one inclusion.

Suppose then that $x \in (A \cap B) \Delta (A \cap C)$. Again, case 1: $x \in A \cap B, x \notin A \cap C$. So we know $x \in A$ and $x \in B$, so the only way $x$ cannot be in $A \cap C$ is when $x \notin C$. Hence $x \in B \Delta C$, and we already had $x \in A$, so $x \in A \cap (B \Delta C)$. The other case is again symmetrical. This shows the other inclusion.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
A \cap (B \Delta C) &=A\cap[(B\cap C^c)\cup (C\cap B^c)]\\
&=[A\cap (B\cap C^c)]\cup [A\cap (C\cap B^c)]\\
&=[(A\cap B)\cap C^c]\cup [(A\cap C)\cap B^c]\\
&=[(A\cap B)\cap C^c\cup A^c]\cup [(A\cap C)\cap B^c\cup A^c]\\
&=[(A\cap B)\cap (C\cap A)^c]\cup [(A\cap C)\cap (B\cap A)^c]\\
&= (A \cap B) \Delta (A \cap C)
\end{align}

Comment: On the line with the 4th equal sign, did you just randomly put $A^c$ on both sides? Why can you do that?

Comment: I did a mistake. I've edited there. The 4-th equality holds since $A\cap B$ and $A^c$ are disjoint.

Answer (score 0):

Keep going: $(A\cap B)\triangle (A\cap C) = [(A\cap B)-(A\cap C)]\cup [(A\cap C)-(A\cap B)]$.

It remains to show that: $(A\cap B) - (A\cap C) = A\cap (B-C)$.

But $LHS = (A\cap B)\cap (A\cap C)' = (A\cap B)\cap (A'\cup C') = (A\cap B\cap A')\cup (A\cap B\cap C') =A\cap B\cap C' = A\cap (B-C)$. The other equation is shown similarly.

Answer (score 0):

There are different answers here that directly tackle the problem with set theoretic calculations. However there is an elegant way to solve your problem by considering indicator functions over sets in $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Given a subset $A$ of the universe $X$, consider the indicator function associated with it: 
$$\chi[A]:X \to \mathbb{F}_2$$ where $\chi[A](x) = 1$  iff $x \in A$. All the addition that follows is modulo $2$ addition. Try proving the following steps:

Step 1: Prove that the following functions are equal:

1. $\chi[A \triangle B] = \chi[A] + \chi[B]$
2. $\chi[A \cap B] = \chi[A].\chi[B]$

Step 2: Since modulo 2 multiplication distributes over addition, you can prove:
\begin{eqnarray}\chi[A \cap (B \triangle C)] &=& \chi[A].(\chi[B] + \chi[C]) \\
                               &=& \chi[A].\chi[B] + \chi[A].\chi[C] \\
                               &=& \chi[A \cap B] + \chi[A\cap C] \\
                               &=& \chi[(A \cap B)\triangle (A\cap C)]
    \end{eqnarray}
Therefore your problem is solved!

This technique is quite powerful since calculations in $\mathbb{F}_2$ (a.k.a modulo $2$) is simple as opposed to tedious set calculations. This method particularly shines in the following exercise:

Prove: $$(A \triangle B) \triangle C = A \triangle (B \triangle C)$$